# How can I upload file by using p-fileupload component more than one time without refreshing Page?

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, primeng

I am using p-fileupload component in angular, but after uploading one file the button is not allowing click event, need to refresh Page to perform another file upload task. Can you please help how can I upload file without refreshing Page

Please find below html code:

```html
<p-fileupload mode="basic" 
              [auto]="true" 
              title="upload file" 
              (onSelect)="upload_document($event);" 
              appHide[roles]=GRANT_ALL_GRP>
</p-fileupload>
```

Comment: Can you share your (relevant) code and html files? Else this becomes a guessing game.

Comment: I added html code

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an array with file(name)s, then after the upload, you can clear the array and then the upload is possible again.

```
<p-fileUpload
   mode="basic"
   [auto]="true"
   [files]="myFiles"
   title="upload file"
   name="myfile[]" 
   [customUpload]="true"
   (uploadHandler)="upload_document($event);" >
</p-fileUpload>
```

In the component:

```js
myFiles: [] = [];

upload_document($event:any){
   console.log("Upload",$event);
   // UPLOAD LOGIC
   this.myFiles = [];
}
```

Comment: Hi Charlie it doesn't work for me but thanks your time and help